# Split list of class into classes with the same values

Tags: c#

I have a class results :

```
class Result
{
    public Performance Result1{ get; set; }
    public Performance Result2{ get; set; }
    public Performance Result3{ get; set; }
    public Performance Result4{ get; set; }
    public string Lane { get; set; }

}
```

the performance enum :

```
public enum Performance
{
    trash,
    verylow,
    low,
    medium,
    good,
    high,
    veryhigh,
    Equals,
    Default,
    NoEnemy
}
```

I'm searching for a cleaner way to  split my list `List<Result> FinalResults`

into lists which have the same Values , for example

```
var Ex1 = new Result {Result1 = Performance.trash, Result2 = Performance.trash, Result3 = Performance.trash};
var Ex2 = new Result {Result1 = Performance.Low, Result2 = Performance.VeryLow, Result3 = Performance.good};
var Ex3 = new Result {Result1 = Performance.high, Result2 = Performance.trash, Result3 = Performance.trash};
var Ex4 = new Result {Result1 = Performance.trash, Result2 = Performance.VeryLow, Result3 = Performance.good};
```

*Ex1* and *Ex4* have the same **result1** so i will have them in the same list , and so *Ex2* and *Ex4* they have the same **result2** etc..

EDIT:

using the following examples I will have those Lists  :

```
List<Result> List1 = {Ex1, Ex2};
List<Result> List1 = {Ex4, Ex4};
```

there is more equals values in those examples but i d like to add in the list **if just *one* Value is equaled.**

EDIT 2 :

I tried to use `GroupBy`  :

```
var low = Current.GamesResults.GroupBy(x => x.result1 == Performance.trash || x.result1 == Performance.verylow
  || x.result1 == Performance.low);
var Normal = Current.GamesResults.GroupBy(x => x.result1 == Performance.good || x.result1 == Performance.Equals
  || x.result1 == Performance.medium);
var High = Current.GamesResults.GroupBy(x => x.result1 == Performance.high || x.result1 == Performance.veryhigh);
```

but the issue is i have to do this alot of times depending on how many property(Result1,rResult2 ...) i have in my **Result class**

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please add the exact output as you would expect to see it, rather than describe it

Comment: @twoleggedhorse i edited my answer , hope its clear

Comment: are you grouping by Result2 and Result3 `.GroupBy(x => Tuple.Create(x.Result2, x.Result3))` ?

Comment: @Slai No i'm grouping by each single property

Comment: can a result be in more than one list if it has low and normal properties?

Comment: @Slai using the class you mentioned can i have the most frequented result in all results ?

Comment: @Slai yes it can be .

Comment: @Slai taking Tuple.Create(t1,t2,t3,t4) does is check using the order ? of it checks only if a result exists in the giving Types ?

Comment: it compares using the order, so might be easier to group by the minimum of the 4 values, or create a method that gets the most frequent of the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the first 3 items in the enum are 0, 1, 2, and the second 3 items are 3, 4, 5, the results can be grouped by the property divided by 3 (not tested):

```
var lookup = Current.GamesResults.ToLookup(r => r.Result1 / 3);
var Low = lookup[0], Normal = lookup[1], High = lookup[2];
```

To use all of the properties will be a bit more complicated, because you will need to make a method that determines the group based on the most frequent properties:

```
int mostFrequent(Result r) => new [] { r.Result1, r.Result2, r.Result3, r.Result4 }
    .GroupBy(p => p).Max(g => Tuple.Create(g.Count(), g.Key)).Item2 / 3;

var lookup = Current.GamesResults.ToLookup(mostFrequent);
var Low = lookup[0], Normal = lookup[1], High = lookup[2];
```